# PDF files fail to load in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: windows-8, adobe-reader, internet-explorer-10

Whenever I browse to a PDF in Internet Explorer (IE10) it doesn't load; I just get a little black&white missing image icon. I'm using Adobe Reader XI and Desktop version of IE.

The same URL used in Chrome loads the PDF in-browser, but I'm at work so I need to keep IE as the default browser.

I've tried disabling the relevant IE add-ons (Adobe PDF Reader and Adobe PDF Link Helper) but nothing changes in either state.

Could this have something to do with IE in Win8 only running in 64bit mode (thus not using 32bit plugins)?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Adobe Reader?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help

Comment: Is it possible to make another free pdf reader your default pdf reader in IE 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe has a page that seems to describe your problem. They suggest various strategies to resolve this issue:

- Restart your computer and try opening the PDF again Open a local copy
  of a PDF in the web browser
- Download the PDF again
- Delete temporary Internet files
- Deselect and then reselect the Display PDF In Browser preference
- Try a different website
- Install the latest version of Reader or Acrobat
- Remove multiple versions of Reader or Acrobat, and then reinstall
  View the PDF in a 32-bit version of the web browser

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html

Comment: None of these suggestions (that are applicible)  fix the problem. One question with the last bullet point, view pdf in a 32-bit browser, how do I know if desktop IE10 in Win8 is running the 32 or 64 bit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Those who having problem regarding PDF file opening in Internet explorer please uninstall the Adobe reader first and do install NITRO Reader,from below link

http://www.nitroreader.com/

Revert me back